# Algorithm for color quantization/reduced image color palette in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, colors, palette

I'm writing a web app that takes a user-submitted image, gets the pixel data via a `canvas` element, does some processing, and then renders the image using vector shapes (using [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)). It's working well, but I end up with several thousand colors, and I'd like to let the user pick a target palette size and reduce the color palette to that size.

At the point where I want to reduce the color space, I'm working with an array of RGB pixel data, like this:

```
[[190,197,190], [202,204,200], [207,214,210], [211,214,211], [205,207,207], ...]
```

I tried the naive option of just removing least-significant bits from the colors, but the results were pretty bad. I've done some research on [color quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) algorithms, but have yet to find a clear description of how to implement one. I could probably work out a cludgy way to send this to the server, run it though an image processing program, and send the resulting palette back, but I'd prefer to do it in JavaScript on the client side.

Does anyone have an example of a clearly explained algorithm that would work here? The goal is to reduce a palette of several thousand colors to a smaller palette optimized for this specific image.

**Edit (7/25/11):** I took @Pointy's suggestion and implemented (most of) Leptonica's MMCQ (modified median cut quantization) in JavaScript. If you're interested, you can [see the code here.](https://gist.github.com/1104622)

**Edit (8/5/11):** The [clusterfck library](http://harthur.github.com/clusterfck/) looks like another great option for this (though I think it's a bit slower than my implementation).

Comment: Instead of just lopping off some bits and leaving it at that, perhaps you could use the 6-bit or 4-bit values for *grouping* the actual colors. Once you identify the groups, you can then compute an average (or median or whatever) for all the actual members of each group.  (Note that I know almost nothing about image processing theory :-)

Comment: ... ha ha, what I typed is what that first paragraph under "Algorithms" says, pretty much :-)

Comment: @Pointy - yup :). I'm hoping someone can provide a good algorithm for this - I get that the basic idea is "cluster, then take the mean of each cluster", but I'm a bit at sea about how to do the clustering.

Comment: I clicked through some of the links from the Wikipedia page and found that the "MMCQ" (the "modified median cut quantization") algorithm is available (in C) from [Leptonica](http://www.leptonica.com/download.html).  It doesn't look trivial, but the code is quite nicely commented and the basic ideas seem pretty understandable (i.e., there's no esoteric moon math or anything).

Comment: I don't know C, so I'm worried that this might take quite a lot of digging. Still, feel free to repost as an answer, so I can at least give you a +1 for it - looks like a good option to investigate.

Comment: Different technology but [here on MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22117) you can download the code for an [ASP.NET Color Quantizer sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479306.aspx) that might interest you.

Comment: @bhargav-rao - the original question here was focused on asking for help with the algorithm, so I don't feel it's off-topic.

Comment: @nrabinowitz I re-read the question, I still feel that it's too broad. (it's slightly off-topic as a tool request too). Secondly even the answers all consist of a small explanation followed by links to more details. My only intention was to prevent future link-only posts. If you [edit] it and make it better, then I'll certainly open it. (But I don't think that's required. Having an old question with lots of upvotes, closed as off topic, doesn't contribute towards a question ban).

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I'll leave it as is for now, I got a helpful answer at the time and the question may be useful to others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the caveat that I don't claim any expertise at all in any field of image processing: I read over the Wikipedia article you linked, and from there found Dan Bloomberg's [Leptonica](http://www.leptonica.com).  From there you can [download](http://www.leptonica.com/download.html) the sources for the algorithms discussed and explained.

The source code is in C, which hopefully is close enough to JavaScript (at least in the core "formula" parts) to be understandable.  The basic ideas behind the "MMCQ" algorithm don't seem super-complicated. It's really just some heuristic tricks for splitting up the 3-dimensional color space into sub-cubes based on the way colors in an image clump together.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for something in pseudo-code or a language I knew - but it looks like now I have a weekend coding project :).

Comment: Did anything ever come from this? I'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 15):

I wrote a web app that extracts a color palette from an image. It allows you to load an image, then play around with three different algorithms/approaches for extracting a color palette from it:

1. **Simple histogramming**
2. **Median Cut**
3. **k-means**

You can find a copy of it running [here](http://palette-maker.herokuapp.com/)

You can find the code for it on [github](https://github.com/mattnedrich/palette-maker)

It's written 100% in Javascript, and uses [Plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/) for the example plots.

I also wrote a post describing the three approaches/algorithms in more detail - you can find that [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/12/07/pixels-and-palettes-extracting-color-palettes-from-images/)

Comment: Cool, thanks for posting!