# compress image color space of set of pixels

Tags: javascript, image, algorithm, colors, compression

I have situation were I have received an uploaded image, resized it to be smaller than 100 by 100, and extracted every pixel's color. So, all my data about the compressed image can be stored in four variables:

`width` - (*int*) the overall width of the image

`height` - (*int*) the overall height of the image

`colors` - (*Array*) an array of objects with unique RGB values

`pixels` - (*Array*) two dimensional array with indexes referencing `colors`

For my implementation, I want to compress the color space to under 20 unique colors. What sort of algorithm should I use to fuse and reduce the number of unique colors my pixels express?

I have no pseudocode for this, but I thought there must be some way to find out the twenty most different colors (using the highest variance in R, G, and B values from the average). Then I would be able to group other colors under one of the other colors they vary least from and average the values each group receives. However, I have no idea how to implement this and remain skeptical of this methods effectiveness.

Ideas?

Comment: Sounds straightforward enough, you just need to figure out how to get a color difference magnitude from two different RGB objects (if that is indeed the approach you're sure you want).

Comment: Problem is that I could have up to 10,000 colors, which is potentially 50 million variances from each other to organize.

Comment: What you're looking for is called [color quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization). It's a well studied field.  I've used an octree algorithm to go from 16-bit color (65536 colors) to 256 colors. The Wikipedia article can get you started, and there are lots of source code examples available. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/6205955/56778

Comment: Note: Your `colors` is often called "color_table" or "palette". But I recommend you to follow BMP format ideas (they support also 16 bit): keep [x][y] array, but just to occupy the expected bits, not aligned to bytes [but so, 16 or 32 colours are better: base 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Jim Mischel. You need to JavaScript library for color quantization.

> Color quantization is the process of reducing an image with thousands
>   or millions of colors to one with fewer (usually 256).

You can use [RgbQuant.js](https://github.com/leeoniya/RgbQuant.js/tree/master) and in the option you can set desired color numbers.

```
// options
var opts = {
    colors: 256, // desired palette size
    //...
};
```

You can see this [demo](http://leeoniya.github.io/RgbQuant.js/demo/) before implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

K-NN clustering to 20 clustes will be optimal in sense of L2 norm minimization between input colors  and output colors